# Working with the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

How is
$$\int_C \exp\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) dz = 2i\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+1)!},$$
where $C: |z| = 1$

I am very conflicted with the summation next to the complex constant. Can you try and give me a hint to the verification of this integral.

Thank you,

Bayerischer

Comment: Hint: $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$. What then is $e^{1/z}$? What is their product?

Comment: Is the right hand side the correct expression? I am getting some other answer... @GregMartin

Comment: @cello what are you getting?

Comment: @Bayerischer :  Your expression is correct.. I could not see at that time that what i am getting is equivalent to what you got.. It is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}=1+\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)+\frac{1}{2!}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2+\cdots$$

Integral, summation can be interchanged..

$$\int_{|z|=1}e^{z+\frac{1}{z}} dz=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{|z|=1}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^n dz
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\int_{|z|=1}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k+1} dz$$

Then prove that 
$$\int_{|z|=1}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k+1} dz=2\pi i\binom{2k+1}{k}=2\pi i\frac{(2k+1)!}{k!(k+1)!}$$

Combining all these we have

$$\int_{|z|=1}e^{z+\frac{1}{z}} dz
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\frac{2\pi i(2k+1)!}{k!(k+1)!}
=2\pi i\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(k+1)!}.$$